# SQL Server performance got slow down suddenly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2. It contains a database named `muri`. And I have created a linked server to proficy historian using iHistorian OLE DB Provider.

I executed some query for linked server. It was working fine until this morning.

When I run this simple query:

```
select * 
from openquery(ihist,'select * from ihtags')
```

it went executing until I close SQL Server. It takes a long time but doesn't complete execution. First I thought SQL Server went slow down. But when I run simple query to my `muri` database as follows.

```
select * from employee
```

it is working perfectly fine. After that I tried to delete existing linked server, this also showed progress as executing but don't complete execution and deletion.

Then I tried to create new linked server with different name, same thing happened with this also.

I can't delete existing linked server, can't create new linked server and can't execute `openquery` as follows

```
select * from openquery(ihist,'select * from ihtags')
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: How long does it take to execute the SELECT against the ihtags table when your run it diresctly on the ihist instance? How many rows are in that table? It looks like either locking/blocking or a huge amount of data being transferred...

Comment: Have you tried restarting the SQL Server instance (the one with the linked server definition)?  Perhaps the iHistorian OLE DB driver is in a bad state.